Is there an official explanation of Call of Duty: Black Ops III's campaign?
The campaign in Call of Duty: Black Ops III is one of my favorite video-game campaigns. However, even I must admit that the story is the schizophrenic love child of Camus, Tim Burton, and Christopher Nolan (although that's a major part of while I like it so much).
While there are various things we know for sure from the game itself (such as that the player character from the first mission dies, that John Taylor isn't actually the villain, etc.), the exact interpretation of events is still rather vague, with several major fan theories emerging over the years:

The entire campaign after the first mission is the player character's dying delusions
The entire campaign after the first mission is a simulation ran by Corvus so that it can figure out its purpose
During the final act (the Zurich mission) Taylor is being controlled by a Corvus-generated doppelgänger, with him managing to confuse the doppelgänger (i.e., the player) into deleting itself.
During the final act, the digital remnant of the first-mission player character has either merged with or taken over Taylor's consciousness, only to get purged out at the end.
Hendricks didn't actually shoot the CEO; it was just a hallucination.

Given all these theories flying about, have Treyarch or Activision ever clarified what actually happened?

I'm somewhat tempted to just answer "Train goes boom."
